# How to check the precise values of variables which invoked a warning with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I ran pytest and got the following warning information:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

x = array([-0.01, -0.01, -0.01,  0.01,  0.01,  0.01])
bounds = (array([-0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01]), array([0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]))

def _check_clip_x(x, bounds):
    if (x < bounds[0]).any() or (x > bounds[1]).any():
>           warnings.warn("Values in x were outside bounds during a "
                      "minimize step, clipping to bounds", RuntimeWarning)
E           RuntimeWarning: Values in x were outside bounds during a minimize step, clipping to bounds

../../anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py:282: RuntimeWarning
```

The problem is, the printed values of `x` and `bounds` are not really helpful because they only show two decimal points. Is there an option that you can add to `pytest -W error *.py` to output the full floating-point form?

Comment: are you referring to using the `-v` flag when running tests? you can use `-vvv` to output the maximum level of verbosity

Comment: This isn't a `pytest` issue. What library provides the array impl? For example, `numpy` has [`set_printoptions(precision=n)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) etc.